# How to write Flutter unit test, when window.parent.postMessage contains jsonEncode?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, flutter-test

How to write Unit Test for this method in Flutter application?

```
void sendEvent() {
    window.parent?.postMessage(
        jsonEncode({
          'sender': 'sender1',
          'event': 'event1',
          'value': true,
        }),
        '*');
  }
```

I tried with> `window.parent!.addEventListener...`
But I don't know how to finish.

Answer (score 0):

I try with mocking Window class, and WindowBase. But I don't know how pass window.postMessage from mock to method for unitTest. How to connect them?

```
      final service=Service();
      var window = MockWindow();
      service.sendEvent();
      verify(window.parent?.postMessage).called(1);
```

How sendEvent connect with mock-window???